# Can't boot from any device: Missing \Boot\BCD

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

With my relatively new PC (a few months) I suddenly can't boot in Windows anymore after a Windows update.
I get the following error:

> 0xc0000225: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors. File: \Boot\BCD

Trying to start recovery gets me the same error.

I have a recovery USB with a bunch of tools. I've tried all of them. Most PE tools display the same BCD error. Windows 10 setup (both from the original DVD and from USB) display the following error:

> Windows cannot read the  setting from the unattended answer file.

I can boot in "boot recovery disk" which is a small Ubuntu based recovery environment. The tool says "boot repaired", but the problem remains.
In that environment, I can read and write on the disk, so the (nvme) disk is at least not fully broken.

I've tried resetting the BIOS to the defaults.

I'm out of ideas.
If I google the error codes, I only find instructions like starting recovery from installation media, doing /bootrec /rebuildbcd, etc. but I can't do any of these, as the installation media isn't starting either.

All help is appreciated!

Extra info: When I disconnect the nmve drive, the Windows setup dvd starts normally. Of course, that doesn't help me, but it at least shows the dvd is OK...

Comment: Rather than using the Windows 10 setup that came with the PC, have you tried downloading the Windows ISO using the Media Creation Tool, and reinstalling from that? Also, since it's a fairly new PC, it might be covered by warranty.

Comment: I can try using the media creation tool. It's a self-built PC so I would first have to find out which component is failing.

Comment: Since this happened immediately after a Windows Update, I'm inclined to think the issue is the OS, not hardware. To test, make a Live USB with another OS, such as Ubuntu. If the Live USB runs (no installation to HD needed), then all your hardware is OK, except possibly the HD. If you can then access the internal SSD or HDD, and all files are OK, then that is OK, as well. You might even want to install Linux, dual boot or stand-alone, if that makes your PC usable.

Comment: So, knowing it's a self-build therefore also self-installed Windows, here's the question: **Did you installed Windows in UEFI or in Legacy ("BIOS") mode?** (Easy to check just with the drive's partitioning type: MBR or "msdos" or "dos" means Legacy; Windows in UEFI mode strictly requires GPT). UEFI mode is recommended in any modern hardware since at least 2012!! If yours was installed in Legacy mode (and your hardware is from the last decade or newer) then anything can happen with this or future updates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was installed in UEFI mode, but I'll double check, thanks